# Date format does not work properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios4

I take date into `string`. `date format` is like this and `string` is

```
datenotification=20-02-2012
```

Now I want to change this into

```
20-feb-2012
```

but for checking purposes I just place that into a `dateformatter` and print that but it shows me an incorrect date

```
NSDateFormatter* currentdateformate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[currentdateformate setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY"];
NSDate *d=[currentdateformate dateFromString:dateNotification];
NSString *str3=[currentdateformate stringFromDate:d];
[currentdateformate release];
```

Comment: what the input of the d please write here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey Check this example

```
 NSString *string = @"12-02-2000";
 NSDateFormatter* currentdateformate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [currentdateformate setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
 NSDate *d=[currentdateformate dateFromString:string];
 [currentdateformate setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
 NSString *str3=[currentdateformate stringFromDate:d];
 [currentdateformate release];
 NSLog(@"S %@",str3);
```

output S 12-feb-2012

Comment: don't use capital "YYYY" as you get the wrong result used small "yyyy" letters